# Transportation optimization task with carrier constraints

Tags: python, python-3.x, pulp

I have a transportation problem with constraints on the load a robot can carry.
There are robots in different places in a warehouse.
And I am optimizing based on distances from robot to stations where the robot can collect some boxes.

The constraint is that a robot can carry 2 boxes IF the height of the first box is below a threshold.
Otherwise it can carry only a single box.
And every station has only 1 box to take.

I succeeded in planning for robots without the load constraint.
So that every robot can carry 2 boxes.

In the example below robot 1 gets station 2 and 3 and robot 2 gets station 1.
So this is fine.

But I am struggling on how to add the box_heights constraint which affects the loadable boxes on the robot.
How would I design this in pulp?

This is my test inout data:

```
optimizer costs: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
optimizer boxes_to_take: {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}
optimizer box_heights: {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1}
optimizer available_space: {1: 2, 2: 2}
optimizer station_ids: [1, 2, 3]
```

Costs explained:

```
    # Stations
    # 1 2 3
    [1, 2, 3],  # S1   Robots
    [4, 5, 6],  # S2
```

So the cost from S2 to Station 3 is 6.

And this is my script: ( copy - paste executable python 3.8 code)

```py
    import logging
    import threading
    import typing

    from pulp import *

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.level = logging.INFO
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)


    class TransportOptimizer:

    def __init__(self):
        logging.info(f"Initializing TransportOptimizer")

    # Takes stations and robots to optimize and returns a new set of optimized stations
    def optimize(self):

        station_ids = [1, 2, 3]
        robot_ids = [1, 2]

        # Creates a dictionary for the number of units a robot can load
        available_space = {}
        for robot_id in robot_ids:
            available_space[robot_id] = 2

        # Creates a dictionary for the number of available boxes
        boxes_to_take = {}
        box_heights = {}
        for station_id in station_ids:
            boxes_to_take[station_id] = 1
            box_heights[station_id] = 1 if station_id % 2 else 2

        logging.debug(f"boxes_to_take: {boxes_to_take}")

        # Creates a list of costs of each transportation path
        costs = [  # Stations
            # 1 2 3
            [1, 2, 3],  # S1   Robots
            [4, 5, 6],  # S2
        ]

        logging.info(f"optimizer costs: {costs}")
        logging.info(f"optimizer boxes_to_take: {boxes_to_take}")
        logging.info(f"optimizer box_heights: {box_heights}")
        logging.info(f"optimizer available_space: {available_space}")
        logging.info(f"optimizer station_ids: {station_ids}")

        # The cost data is made into a dictionary
        costs = makeDict([robot_ids, station_ids], costs, 0)
        # Creates the 'problem' variable to contain the problem data
        problem = LpProblem("FullCostOptimizer", LpMinimize)
        # Creates a list of tuples containing all the possible routes for transport
        Routes = [(robot_id, station_id) for robot_id in robot_ids for station_id in station_ids]
        # A dictionary called 'Vars' is created to contain the referenced variables(the routes)
        vars = LpVariable.dicts("Route", (robot_ids, station_ids), 0, None, LpInteger)
        # The objective function is added to 'problem' first
        problem += (
            lpSum([vars[robot_id][station_id] * costs[robot_id][station_id] for (robot_id, station_id) in Routes]),
            "Sum_of_Transporting_Costs",
        )
        # The maximum loadable boxes constraints are added to problem for each robot
        for robot_id in robot_ids:
            problem += lpSum([vars[robot_id][station_id] for station_id in station_ids]) <= available_space[
                robot_id], f"sum_of_boxes_robot {robot_id}_can_load"
        # The minimum boxes constraints are added to problem for each station
        for station_id in station_ids:
            problem += lpSum([vars[robot_id][station_id] for robot_id in robot_ids]) >= boxes_to_take[
                station_id], "sum_of_boxes_on_station_%s" % station_id

        station_id = 1
        robot_id = 1
        logging.info(
            f"robot {robot_id} and station {station_id}: {vars[robot_id][station_id]}, sum={lpSum([vars[robot_id][station_id] for station_id in station_ids]) <= available_space[robot_id]}")

        logging.info(f"optimizer problem: {problem}")

        # The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
        problem.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False))
        # The status of the solution is printed to the screen
        logging.debug(f"Status: {LpStatus[problem.status]}")
        # Each of the variables is printed with it's resolved optimum value
        for v in problem.variables():
            logging.debug(f"{v.name} = {v.varValue}")
        # The optimised objective function value is printed to the screen
        logging.debug(f"Total Cost of Transportation = {value(problem.objective)}")

        logging.debug(problem.sol_status)
        logging.info(f"Total cost: {problem.objective.value()}")
        logging.info(f"vars: {problem.variables()}")

        for v in problem.variables():
            route, robot, station = str.split(v.name, sep='_')
            logging.info(f"robot {robot} to station {station} = {v.varValue} {'valid' if v.varValue == 1 else ''}")

        if problem.sol_status != 1:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Solver failed with status {problem.sol_status}")


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        optimizer = TransportOptimizer()
        optimized_tasks = optimizer.optimize()
```

Comment: Your model setup is confusing...  I think partly because you have 3 boxes and 3 stations.  So, what should happen in your model if (1) there were 5 boxes going to a particular station?  How could that be represented?  (2) if there were 2 boxes and the "first" (separate issue) is too tall, what happens to the 2nd box and how is that represented?  Lastly, you mention if the "first" box it too tall.  What makes a box "first"?  Why wouldn't our super-smart robot just pick a short box as first and always have room for #2 (pun intended).

Comment: We collect boxes from a station and not to it. Every station has only 1 box to collect.
1. If stations and robots are not equal I would balance them but I let this out for simplicity.  So I would introduce some fake robot/station for the solver.
2. At the moment a box is selected simply by the cost to the station the robot would collect it from. So the check if the box fits on a robot is part of the question.